# Wie nennt man jemanden, dessen Kritik sich an einer Utopie orientiert und welcher keine Lösungen bereit hat?

Tags: phrase-request

Gibt es ein Wort für jemanden, der alles an einer Utopie misst, aber keine Lösungen bereit hat?

Natürlich braucht es Utopien als Richtungsweiser zur Weiterentwicklung des wissenschaftlichen Wissens. Gibt es aber einen Begriff für Menschen die sich ausschliesslich auf die Wertung gemessen an einer Utopie beschränken ohne je empirisch Lösungen zu finden?

Comment: Wenn es nur um politische Themen geht würde das Wort Demagoge passen. Erfahrungsgemäss ist diese Denkart aber auch ausserhalb der Politik verbreitet

Answer (score 5):

Ich glaube, am besten passt der Begriff **Utopist.** Hier ist die Definition aus [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopist):

> Als **Utopist** wird der Vertreter einer Weltanschauung bezeichnet, dessen soziale und politische Gesellschaftskritik von Idealvorstellungen geleitet werden, die in den Augen seiner Kritiker als spekulativ und wirklichkeitsfremd gelten, statt sich pragmatisch an den mängelbehafteten Realitäten zu orientieren.

Da haben wir also sowohl das wirklichkeitsfremde Ziel, als auch die Abneigung, sich mit der Realität zu befassen.

Alternative Begriffe sind:

- **Perfektionist**
  Der Perfektionist hat einen (unter Umständen unerreichbaren) Idealzustand als Ziel, versucht aber auch Lösungen zu finden, um diesen Zustand zu erreichen.
- **Idealist**
  Mit dem Utopisten vergleichbar, aber positiver besetzt. Der Idealist kann Wegweiser für Leute sein, die vielleicht mehr Bodenhaftungen haben. Der Utopist hingegen wird selten als Vorbild wahrgenommen.
- **Nörgler**
  Das ist keine echte Alternative zu den genannten Begriffen, ich erwähne den Nörgler nur der Vollständigkeit halber: Der Nörgler kritisiert alles, ohne Lösungen bereit zu stellen. Im Gegensatz zum Utopisten hat der Nörgler aber nicht nur keine Lösung, sondern auch keine Vorstellung von einem zu erreichenden Zustand. Der Nörgler empfindet nur, dass der realisierte Zustand schlecht ist.

Comment: Vielleicht solltest Du doch einmal "Die Letzten Tage der Menschheit" lesen - dann bekommst du auch ein anderes Bild vom Nörgler.

Comment: @bakunin: Die Figur namens "Nörgler" in der zusammenhanglosen Szenensammlung von Karl Kraus heißt zwar *Nörgler,* ist aber kein Nörgler, sondern eher ein Advocatus Diaboli, der als Gesprächspartner der Figur mit dem Namen *Optimist* dessen Ansichten angreift. Der Kraussche *Nörgler* ergibt erst gemeinsam mit dem *Optimist* einen Sinn, während ein echter Nörgler keinen Gegenpart braucht um an allem und jedem etwas auszusetzen. (Ich habe 20 Jahre lang in Wien, der Hauptstadt der Nörgler, gelebt und weis daher sehr gut, was ein echter Nörgler ist.)

Answer (score 4):

Ein Verwandter des Utopisten ist der

> Fantast/Phantast,

ein Mensch mit überspannten, i. d. R. nicht umsetzbaren Ideen.
Abwertend könnte man so einen als

> Träumer

bezeichnen.

Answer (score 2):

Im politischen Kontext passt "Fundamentalist".